# Powershell scheduled task on windows 7 that runs when admin account is not logged in

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I am writing a powershell function that runs on a Server to schedule a powershell script to run on each Windows 7 client machine by using schtasks.exe.

If I do not provide a user name and password, the script only runs if the client is logged in as administrator.

If I do provide a user name and password, I get two errors:
(1) System cannot find the file specified
(2) A specified logon session does not exist.  It may already have been terminated.

How do I get the scheduled job to run properly even if the admin account is not logged it?

Thanks!

```
function scheduleRemoteScript($computerList) {
    foreach ($computer in $computerList) {            
        $ts = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1
        $currentDateTime = (get-date) + $ts
        $hour = $currentDateTime.Hour.ToString()
        if ($hour.Length -eq 1) {
            $hour = '0' + $hour
        }
        $minute = $currentDateTime.Minute.ToString()
        if ($minute.Length -eq 1) {
            $minute = '0' + $minute
        }
        $timeString = $hour + ":" + $minute
        schtasks.exe /Delete /TN LocalScript /S $computer /F #delete the task in case it aleady exists.

        #this runs when logged in with admin account, but not user account.
        #schtasks.exe /create /TN LocalScript /S $computer /ST $timeString /SC ONCE /TR "powershell.exe -file C:\localScript.ps1" 

        #this gives two errors: (1) system cannot find the file specified  (2) a specified logon session does not exist.  It may already have been terminated.
        schtasks.exe /create /TN LocalScript /S $computer /ST $timeString /SC ONCE /TR "powershell.exe -file C:\localScript.ps1" /RU 'admin-account' /RP 'somePassword'         
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? (I don't mean the task scheduling. What are you using the scheduler to try to do?)

Comment: I'm using a powershell script to install patches on isolated network client computers.  I want the scheduler to kick off the script interactively (console window displays) immediately after the script and patches have been distributed to the clients.

Comment: I would suggest to use WSUS rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.